# Shared data with typescript transfromers

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Currently I am fiddling around with typescript transformers. Therefore I am wondering if it is possible to share data between two typescript transformers?

Greets Lukas

Comment: Please be more specific

Comment: I asked this question because I would like to solve this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61718877/13513418

As stated in the question I do not really know how to solve this problem - I do not know how to follow the module import and adjust the corresponding class.

Therefore I had the idea to find all the classes which have to be transformed with the first transformer...

...and then adjust the targets/classes with the second transformer.

The array of targets (maybe symbols of the class definitions) would have to be shared between the two transformers.

Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @lukmac please update your original answer, explaining what you mean by "transformed" and "adjust the corresponding class", it may be helpful to provide examples of what you expect to receive. Also, https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-transformer may be of use (possibly).

Comment: I updated the description in the referenced question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61718877/typescript-transformer-follow-module-imports

Hopefully it gets clearer with the use case in mind. As a matter of fact it is not important how I would like to change the class definition. I just have to find the class definition that I could do it. But I tried to explain this in the referenced link.

With "adjust" and "transformed" I just mean changes done with the typescript transformer.